# React - props not available after page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm using props in my app, which are fetched using:"

```
export default withTracker(() => {
    let custAccounts = Meteor.subscribe('allAccounts');
    return {
        ready: custAccounts.ready(),
        custs: Meteor.users.find({}).fetch()
    }
})(Forward);
```

Then in componentDidmount():

```
componentDidMount(){

    if (this.state.isMounted) {
        Meteor.call('getCurrentCF', this.props.custs[0].subscriber_id, (err, res) => {
            if (!err) {
                var result = JSON.parse(res.content);
                if (typeof result.cfu['destinations'] != 'undefined') {

                    if(result.cfu['destinations'][0].destination === "voicebox") {
                        this.setState({
                            cfActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik',
                            vbActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik-active',
                        });
                    } else {
                        this.setState({
                            cfActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik-active',
                            vbActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik',
                            currentCFDest: "(" + result.cfu['destinations'][0].simple_destination + ")",
                        });
                    }

                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        cfActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik',
                        vbActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik',
                    });
                }

                Meteor.call('getCurrentVM', this.props.custs[0].subscriber_id, (err, res) => {
                    if(!err) {
                        var vms = JSON.parse(res.content);

                        this.setState({
                            vmCount: vms.total_count,
                            isLoading: false
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                });

            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When a users freshly log in to the app, all data is there and you can user the app. But when you (accidentally) refresh, the console states an error that:

> Cannot read property 'subscriber_id' of undefined

I can't seem to find out why. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it fetched on the same page and set as a prop on the same page you are refreshing? And if so, the call might be synchronous and not available when the component is mounted. If not, then you would have to go through the process again. I would look into (and highly recommend) a storage state management system like `redux`, which solves this issue or just use `localstorage` directly.

Comment: Yes it is. I'm using the same method in my admin environment and here no issues with reloading. All the props keep their values. The way I do it is first create a component and then export it using the withtracker, which adds the fetched data as props.